# query to bring columns in single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below

```
    CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
      `fruit_id` int(11) default NULL,
      `fruit_name` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL
    );
```

The table contains fields as below

```
    INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_id, fruit_name) 
               VALUES (101, 'Mango'),
                      (102, 'Apple'),
                      (103, 'Orange'),
                      (104, 'Pineapple'),
                      (105, 'Lemon'),
                      (106, 'Custard');
```

I want a select query which brings the column in to single row as below for particular id 
like

```
    SELECT fruit_id, fruit_name
       FROM fruits
      WHERE fruit_id = 101
```

The above query bring output in two columns

```
    101    Mango
```

I want the columns in single row as below

```
    101
    Mango
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT row
FROM
(
  SELECT fruit_id, fruit_id row FROM fruits
  UNION
  SELECT fruit_id, fruit_name row FROM fruits
) s
WHERE fruit_id = 101;
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33fe0/2)

Comment: can you show me the records returned? *like screenshot would do*

Comment: try this `SELECT s.row
FROM
(
  SELECT fruit_id, fruit_id row FROM fruits
  UNION
  SELECT fruit_id, fruit_name row FROM fruits
) s
WHERE s.fruit_id = 101;`

Comment: John I tried above schema in my MySQL 5.5 and both your queries are working fine, but for some reasons queries are not working on his side.

Comment: @user1785551 try it again, this time I added `casting` [***SQLFiddle Demo: click here***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33fe0/11)